# Getting error in /bin/sh when trying to use a makefile

Tags: command-line, compiling, make, macos

I am trying to compile a file using a makefile but for some reason, I am getting an error in `/bin/sh`, I am getting the following:

```
nvc FLAGS(LDFLAGS) black_scholes.o gaussian.o main.o parser.o random.o dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.o timer.o util.o -o hw1.x
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `nvc FLAGS(LDFLAGS) black_scholes.o gaussian.o main.o parser.o random.o dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.o timer.o util.o -o hw1.x'
make: *** [Makefile:16: hw1.x] Error 1
```

Here is the content of my makefile:

```
LDFLAGS += -Ldcmt0.4/lib -ldcmt
include Makefile.include


HW1_INCS = black_scholes.h gaussian.h parser.h random.h timer.h util.h
HW1_C_SRCS = black_scholes.c gaussian.c main.c parser.c random.c dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.c timer.c util.c
HW1_C_OBJS = $(HW1_C_SRCS:.c=.o)
HW1_EXE = hw1.x

all: hw1.x

%.o: %.c

$(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(ACCFLAGS) $< -o $@

hw1.x: $(HW1_C_OBJS) dcmt0.4/lib/libdcmt.a
$(CC) $LFLAGS$ (LDFLAGS) $(HW1_C_OBJS) -o $@

dcmt0.4/lib/libdcmt.a: 
make -C dcmt0.4/lib
black_scholes.o: black_scholes.c black_scholes.h gaussian.h random.h util.h
gaussian.o: gaussian.c gaussian.h util.h
main.o: main.c black_scholes.h parser.h random.h timer.h
parser.o: parser.c parser.h
random.o: random.c random.h
dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.o: dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.c
timer.o: timer.c timer.h
util.o: util.c util.h

clean:

make -C dcmt0.4/lib clean

rm -f $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_EXE)
```

and here is the content of my makefile.include

```
CC = nvc
LINKER = nvc
LDFLAGS = -lm
```

I don;t really understand where the error is in the first place as usually errors in makefile indicate an error there and not in `/bin/sh` , any help understand or fixing the error would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors are in this line:

```
$(CC) $LFLAGS$ (LDFLAGS) $(HW1_C_OBJS) -o $@
```

`$LFLAGS` is interpreted as `$L` followed by `FLAGS`; then `$ (LDFLAGS)` is interpreted as `$`  (the value of the variable whose name is a single space) followed by `(LDFLAGS)`, which is why you get the `FLAGS(LDFLAGS)` output.

To fix it, use

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(HW1_C_OBJS) -o $@
```

Comment: thanks a lot, any idea why the error was marked in /bin/sh? I am pretty new to using makefiles and usual errors are indicated in the makefile directly

Comment: The errors don’t render the Makefile syntactically invalid, so Make accepts it; the error arises because the command is syntactically invalid shell, so `/bin/sh` rejects it.